# pandas DataFrame column manipulation using previous row value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have below pandas DataFrame

| color | direction | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1.0 | 1.0 | NaN |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0 |
| -1.0 | 1.0 | NaN |
| 1.0 | -1.0 | NaN |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0 |

I am trying to update the total column based on below logic.

if df['color'] == 1.0 and df['direction'] == 1.0 then Total should be Total of previous row + 1. if Total of previous row is NaN, then 0+1

Note: I was trying to read the previous row total using df['Total'].shift() + 1 but it didnt work.

**Expected DataFrame.**

| color | direction | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1.0 | 1.0 | NaN |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 1 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 2 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 3 |
| -1.0 | 1.0 | NaN |
| 1.0 | -1.0 | NaN |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 1 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the sub-groupby value with `cumsum` , the new just `groupby` with color and direction and do `cumcount`

```
df.loc[df.Total.notnull(),'Total'] = df.groupby([df['Total'].isna().cumsum(),df['color'],df['direction']]).cumcount()+1
df
Out[618]: 
   color  direction  Total
0   -1.0        1.0    NaN
1    1.0        1.0    1.0
2    1.0        1.0    2.0
3    1.0        1.0    3.0
4   -1.0        1.0    NaN
5    1.0       -1.0    NaN
6    1.0        1.0    1.0
7    1.0        1.0    2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i may ask, does the group by behave same way as above if the color and direction both have -1.0. I do not want to have the count if either one of color or direction is -1.0 . obviously its possible that both can be -1.0 as well, in that case i want to retain NaN in total.

Comment: @MohanramKrishnan you can do that as well , just need to assign it without use df.Total.notnull()